# Jenkins view to list jobs matching two conditions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Need some help regarding jenkins job view;

I need to have one Jenkins view which matches two conditions

1. Specific Job name (ex: all the jobs which has *trunk* as one of the string in job name)
2. and Job Status;

Basically i need to list all the jobs which has job name containing *trunk* and which is failed under one view.

I know there is sectioned view and list view where we can list the jobs based any one of the condition above but i need to match both the condition.. is there a way to do this using any of the Jenkins Plugins?

Appreciate your help in this regard.

Regrds,
Raju.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [View Job Filters](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters) plugin for this - it lets you build views which chain together filters to create the custom views, and the filter options include:

- Job name, including regular expression filters (i.e. you could filter by `^.*trunk.*$`)
- Job status

I think that should allow you to build the list view you need. The image below shows an example taken from the build system I manage, where we were able to create a view with the same characteristics as you require (naturally exchange `labos` for `trunk`).

[image]

Comment: thanks i tried with *View Job Filters* plugin; i believe there is some kind of bug or something it is doesnt filter out based on regular expression;


for example i have jobs by name *cRNC_trunk_cch_smoke_MT*

i added the filter by regular expression as ^.*trunk.*$ but still view displays all the jobs :(

Comment: I think it worked the second filter i was choosing was incorrect :) thanks million

Comment: Any idea how can i add regular expression to check for two strings in job name for ex: in job name *cRNC_trunk_cch_smoke_MT* check for both *trunk* as well as *MT*

Comment: `^.*trunk.*MT.*$` (`^` means start of string, `.*` means 0 or more of anything and `$` means end of string) - might be worth reading up on regular expressions.